# Why is Akka-Http Routing going wrong here?

Tags: scala, akka-http

So basically, I'm writing some code that will make it possible for users to upload a file to a server. I've already succeeded in uploading a file via an HTML form (with MultiPart.FormData), but when I try 'curl -X POST -F file="filepath" localhost:8080/upload', I get a '404 not found' message.

I already read the documentation about Akka, but I just can't get to know why it works in one way and not in the other. What am I doing wrong here?

```
val route =
  post {
    path("upload") {
      fileUpload("file") {
        case (metadata, byteSource) => 
          val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("path of the image") resolve metadata.fileName)
          val writeResult = byteSource.runWith(sink)
          onSuccess(writeResult) { _ =>
            complete("file got uploaded")
          }
      }
    }
  } ~
    complete("404 not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in [path directive source](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/PathDirectives.scala#L32) that it accepts a path prefix with the path end. So if you use `path("upload")` it will accept only paths ended with `/upload/` but won't accept paths ended with `/upload` (without path end symbol `/`).

If you wont to use both `/upload/` and `/upload` paths, you should use

```
pathPrefix("upload") ~ pathEndOrSingleSlash
```

Also, you can use [ignoreTrailingSlash directive](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/ignoreTrailingSlash.html).

Comment: Curious, should it be "/upload" for   localhost:8080/upload to work, or does it assume slash before? Since it's path-prefix

Comment: Yes, pathPrefix("upload") matches "/upload" and path("upload") matches "/upload/"

Comment: The key difference here that pathPrefix doesn't require the path end (hence it can be followed with other path's directives).

Comment: Well it gets weirder, because if I try  'curl -X POST -F file="filepath" localhost:8080/upload/'or try the pathPrefix solution, I still get the 404 message...

Comment: Are you sure you bind to localhost:8080?

Comment: yes, in the meanwhile I wrote a test that posts a multipart containing a simple csv, and that works. I still can't figure out why it doesn't work using curl...